# Python.NET & TensorFlow & CUDA: Could not load dynamic library 'cublas64_11.dll'

Tags: python, c#, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, python.net

I am current working on using [Python.NET](https://pythonnet.github.io/) to build C# environments for interaction [TensorFlow Agents](https://www.tensorflow.org/agents) and am receiving a TensorFlow error attempting to load Cuda DLLs.

When I run pure python examples Tensor flow loads the CUDA DLLs without issue:

```
2021-04-19 03:22:41.062449: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
2021-04-19 03:22:41.062943: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_11.dll
2021-04-19 03:22:41.063347: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublasLt64_11.dll
2021-04-19 03:22:41.063709: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2021-04-19 03:22:41.064088: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2021-04-19 03:22:41.064455: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2021-04-19 03:22:41.064832: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_11.dll
2021-04-19 03:22:41.065202: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_8.dll
```

However, when I run an environment that uses a Python environment that is essentially a wrapper for an environment written in C# using Python.Net is recieve errors the Cuda DLLs were not found:

```
2021-04-19 03:15:14.884746: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'cublas64_11.dll'; dlerror: cublas64_11.dll not found
2021-04-19 03:15:14.885031: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'cublasLt64_11.dll'; dlerror: cublasLt64_11.dll not found
2021-04-19 03:15:14.885281: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'cufft64_10.dll'; dlerror: cufft64_10.dll not found
2021-04-19 03:15:14.885586: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'curand64_10.dll'; dlerror: curand64_10.dll not found
2021-04-19 03:15:14.885851: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'cusolver64_10.dll'; dlerror: cusolver64_10.dll not found
2021-04-19 03:15:14.886174: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'cusparse64_11.dll'; dlerror: cusparse64_11.dll not found
2021-04-19 03:15:14.886454: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'cudnn64_8.dll'; dlerror: cudnn64_8.dll not found
```

Minimal code to reproduce the issue:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from TicTacToeSharpEnvironmentWrapper import TicTacToeEnvironment
env = TicTacToeEnvironment()
physical_devices = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
```

With TicTacToeSharpEnvironmentWrapper.py

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tf_agents.environments import py_environment
from tf_agents.specs import BoundedArraySpec
from tf_agents.trajectories.time_step import StepType
from tf_agents.trajectories.time_step import TimeStep
import numpy as np

assembly_path1 = r"C:\DesktopGym\bin\Debug"
import sys

sys.path.append(assembly_path1)
import clr
clr.AddReference("GymSharp")
from GymSharp import TicTacToeSharpEnvironment

"""A CSharp environment for Tic-Tac-Toe game."""
class TicTacToeEnvironment(py_environment.PyEnvironment):
  """A state-settable environment for Tic-Tac-Toe game.
  """

def __init__(self):
     super(TicTacToeEnvironment, self).__init__()
     self.sharp_env = TicTacToeSharpEnvironment()
```

TicTacToeSharpEnvironment is a c# class libary compiled as 64bit dll

```cs
public class TicTacToeSharpEnvironment
{
    static TicTacToeSharpEnvironment()
    {
        PythonInitiliazer.InitializePython();
    }
}
```

And PythonInitiliazer is used to initalize Python.Net

```cs
public class PythonInitiliazer
{
    static PythonInitiliazer()
    {
        InitializePython();
    }
    static bool initialized;
    public static void InitializePython()
    {
        if (!initialized)
        {
            initPython();
            initialized = true;
        }
    }
    private static void initPython()
    {

        string pathToVirtualEnv = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\";

        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", pathToVirtualEnv, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PYTHONHOME", pathToVirtualEnv, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PYTHONPATH", $"{pathToVirtualEnv}\\Lib\\site-packages;{pathToVirtualEnv}\\Lib;{pathToVirtualEnv}\\scripts", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
        Runtime.PythonDLL = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Shared\\Python37_64\\python37.dll";

        PythonEngine.PythonHome = pathToVirtualEnv;
        PythonEngine.PythonPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PYTHONPATH", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
        PythonEngine.Initialize();
    }
}
```

The full code works. The Python Wrapper of the C# environment passes the [Tensorflow Agents](https://github.com/tensorflow/agents) unit tests for the [Tic Tac Toe environment](https://github.com/tensorflow/agents/blob/master/tf_agents/environments/examples/tic_tac_toe_environment_test.py). The C# environment can be wrapped as Python or a Tensor flow environment and the various agents can train against the environment.

I don't think this is a compatibility issue using the x64 .Net DLL because I am using 64 bit python, but I a can't be certain.

Additional Details:

1. GeForce RTX 3080 (computeCapability: 8.6)
2. Windows 10 20H2
3. Net Framework 4.8 (Compiled with Visual Studio 2019)
4. Python 3.7 (64-bit)
5. Nvidia CUDA 11.
6. Tensforflow-gpu 2.4.1
7. Tf-Agents 0.7.1
8. pythonnet 3.0.0-preview2021-04-03

What else could be causing this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue.  It was due to bad Python.Net wiki documentation showing how to use [Python.Net in a virtual environment](https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/wiki/Using-Python.NET-with-Virtual-Environments).

The fix, for others facing this or very similar issues, is to not use the code in the Wiki:

```cs
var pathToVirtualEnv = @"path\to\env";

Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", pathToVirtualEnv, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
```

Doing so will overwrite your `PATH` environmental variable.

Instead, append the path to your python virtual environment to your existing `PATH` environmental variable.

Instead, append the path to your virtual environment to your `PATH` environmental variable.

```cs
string pathToVirtualEnv = @"path\to\env";

var path = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH");
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", path + ";" + pathToVirtualEnv, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
```